# LRU caching decorator that caches in the instance and in a shared cache

Tags: python, cache, django

I needed a caching decorator, that could be used with methods and functions, that could take typed args and kwargs, and that was Python 2.7 compatible.  Therefore I started with a backport of the `lru_cache` from Python 3.3.  However, I also needed the ability to incorporate a shared cache (I am doing this currently via the Django cache framework) so that items that were not locally available in cache could still avoid more expensive and complex queries by hitting a shared cache.

I don't have a ton of experience writing performance optimized code so am interested in any feedback on ways to improve this.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.core.cache import get_cache
from collections import namedtuple
from functools import update_wrapper
from threading import RLock
import logging
try:
    from spooky import hash128 as hash
except:
    from hashlib import sha256
    hash = lambda x: sha256(x).hexdigest()
import inspect


logger = logging.getLogger('frontpage')
_CacheInfo = namedtuple("CacheInfo", ["l1_hits", "l1_misses", "l2_hits", "l2_misses", "l1_maxsize", "l1_currsize"])


def _make_key(user_function, args, kwds, typed,
             kwd_mark = (object(),),
             fasttypes = {int, str, frozenset, type(None)},
             sorted=sorted, tuple=tuple, type=type, len=len, inst_attr='id'):
    'Make a cache key from optionally typed positional and keyword arguments'
    args = list(args)
    if len(args) > 0:
        if inspect.ismethod(getattr(args[0], user_function.__name__, None)):
            instance = args.pop(0)
            try:
                key = ["{c}{i}".format(c=instance.__class__, i=getattr(instance, inst_attr)), user_function.__name__]
            except:
                key = ["{c}{i}".format(c=instance.__class__, i=instance.__hash__()), user_function.__name__]
        else:
            key = ["", user_function.__name__]
    else:
        key = ["", user_function.__name__]
    if args:
        key.append(tuple(args))
    if kwds:
        key.append(tuple())
        sorted_items = sorted(kwds.items())
        key[-1] += kwd_mark
        for item in sorted_items:
            key[-1] += item
    if typed:
        key.append(tuple(type(v) for v in args))
        if kwds:
            key[-1] += tuple(type(v) for k, v in sorted_items)
    return hash(str(key).encode('utf-8'))



def lru2cache(l1_maxsize=128, none_cache=False, typed=False, l2cache_name='default', inst_attr='id'):
    """Least-recently-used cache decorator.

    If *l1_maxsize* is set to None, the LRU features are disabled and the cache
    can grow without bound.

    If *typed* is True, arguments of different types will be cached separately.
    For example, f(3.0) and f(3) will be treated as distinct calls with
    distinct results.

    Arguments to the cached function must be hashable.

    View the cache statistics named tuple (l1_hits, l1_misses, l2_hits, l2_misses,
    l1_maxsize, l1_currsize) with
    f.cache_info().  Clear the cache and statistics with f.cache_clear().
    Access the underlying function with f.__wrapped__.

    See:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms#Least_Recently_Used

    """

    # Users should only access the lru_cache through its public API:
    #       cache_info, cache_clear, and f.__wrapped__
    # The internals of the lru_cache are encapsulated for thread safety and
    # to allow the implementation to change (including a possible C version).

    l2cache = get_cache(l2cache_name)

    def decorating_function(user_function):

        cache = dict()
        stats = [0, 0, 0, 0]                  # make statistics updateable non-locally
        L1_HITS, L1_MISSES, L2_HITS, L2_MISSES = 0, 1, 2, 3     # names for the stats fields
        make_key = _make_key
        cache_get = cache.get           # bound method to lookup key or return None
        _len = len                      # localize the global len() function
        lock = RLock()                  # because linkedlist updates aren't threadsafe
        root = []                       # root of the circular doubly linked list
        root[:] = [root, root, None, None]      # initialize by pointing to self
        nonlocal_root = [root]                  # make updateable non-locally
        PREV, NEXT, KEY, RESULT = 0, 1, 2, 3    # names for the link fields

        if l1_maxsize == 0:
            def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
                # size limited caching that tracks accesses by recency
                key = make_key(user_function, args, kwds, typed, inst_attr=inst_attr)
                result = l2wrapper(key, user_function, none_cache, *args, **kwds)
                stats[L1_MISSES] += 1
                return result

        elif l1_maxsize is None:
            def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
                # size limited caching that tracks accesses by recency
                key = make_key(user_function, args, kwds, typed, inst_attr=inst_attr)
                result = cache_get(key, root)   # root used here as a unique not-found sentinel
                if result is not root:
                    stats[L1_HITS] += 1
                    return result

                result = l2wrapper(key, user_function, none_cache, *args, **kwds)
                if none_cache or result is not None:
                    cache[key] = result
                stats[L1_MISSES] += 1
                return result

        else:
            def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
                # size limited caching that tracks accesses by recency
                key = make_key(user_function, args, kwds, typed, inst_attr=inst_attr)
                with lock:
                    link = cache_get(key)
                    if link is not None:
                        # record recent use of the key by moving it to the front of the list
                        root, = nonlocal_root
                        link_prev, link_next, key, result = link
                        link_prev[NEXT] = link_next
                        link_next[PREV] = link_prev
                        last = root[PREV]
                        last[NEXT] = root[PREV] = link
                        link[PREV] = last
                        link[NEXT] = root
                        stats[L1_HITS] += 1
                        return result
                result = l2wrapper(key, user_function, none_cache, *args, **kwds)
                if none_cache or result is not None:
                    with lock:
                        root, = nonlocal_root
                        if key in cache:
                            # getting here means that this same key was added to the
                            # cache while the lock was released.  since the link
                            # update is already done, we need only return the
                            # computed result and update the count of l1_misses.
                            pass
                        elif _len(cache) >= l1_maxsize:
                            # use the old root to store the new key and result
                            oldroot = root
                            oldroot[KEY] = key
                            oldroot[RESULT] = result
                            # empty the oldest link and make it the new root
                            root = nonlocal_root[0] = oldroot[NEXT]
                            oldkey = root[KEY]
                            oldvalue = root[RESULT]
                            root[KEY] = root[RESULT] = None
                            # now update the cache dictionary for the new links
                            try:
                                del cache[oldkey]
                            except KeyError:
                                pass
                            cache[key] = oldroot
                        else:
                            # put result in a new link at the front of the list
                            last = root[PREV]
                            link = [last, root, key, result]
                            last[NEXT] = root[PREV] = cache[key] = link
                        stats[L1_MISSES] += 1
                    return result
                else:
                    return result

        def l2wrapper(key, user_function, none_cache, *args, **kwds):
            result = l2cache.get(key)
            if result is not None:
                stats[L2_HITS] += 1
                return result
            result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
            if none_cache or result is not None:
                stats[L2_MISSES] += 1
                l2cache.add(key, result)
            return result   

        def cache_info():
            """Report cache statistics.  This only affects the instance cache and dose not
            impact data stored in l2 Cache"""
            with lock:
                return _CacheInfo(stats[L1_HITS], stats[L1_MISSES], stats[L2_HITS], stats[L2_MISSES], l1_maxsize, len(cache))

        def cache_clear():
            """Clear the cache and cache statistics.  This only affects the instance cache and dose not
            impact data stored in l2 Cache"""
            with lock:
                cache.clear()
                root = nonlocal_root[0]
                root[:] = [root, root, None, None]
                stats[:] = [0, 0, 0, 0]

        def invalidate(*args, **kwds):
            """Delete a specific cache key if it exists"""
            key = make_key(user_function, args, kwds, typed, inst_attr=inst_attr)
            try:
                del cache[key]
            except:
                pass
            try:
                l2cache.delete(key)
            except:
                pass

        wrapper.__wrapped__ = user_function
        wrapper.invalidate = invalidate
        wrapper.cache_info = cache_info
        wrapper.cache_clear = cache_clear
        return update_wrapper(wrapper, user_function)

    return decorating_function
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some great answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll be completely honest - I don't understand what `_make_key` is doing, how, or why.  I could probably figure it out with some digging, but it seems that it could be better documented and commented.

One huge issue is that you have a bare `except:` in it - this is literally never a good idea. It looks like you want to catch an `AttributeError` - just do that.  Even better, you could use the optional default value argument.

```
key = ["{c}{i}".format(c=instance.__class__, i=getattr(instance, inst_attr, hash(instance))), user_function.__name__]
```

You would also benefit from making things shorter - I like the PEP8 80 character per line limit (this is the formatting style I like, but use whatever you prefer).

```
key = ["{c}{i}".format(
           c=instance.__class__,
           i=getattr(instance, inst_attr, hash(instance))
       ), user_function.__name__]
```

You have a bit of unnecessary repetition in assigning the other value to `key`. I think I would rather do something like

```
if len(args) > 0 and inspect.ismethod(getattr(args[0], user_function.__name__, None)):
    key = ....
else:
    key = ["", user_function.__name__]
```

You could use comprehensions in here to make things a bit cleaner

```
if kwds:
    tuple_ = (kwd_mark,) + tuple(item for item in sorted(kwds.items()))
    key.append(tuple_)
```

You have a potential bug in the `if typed` section - in the case where `typed` is truthy but `kwds` is falsy (which may never happen) you're going to get a `NameError` - resolve this by creating `sorted_items` above the `if` statements, then use that within the sections below.

You should format your docstrings to match with some specific style guide - that'll make it easier for something like Sphinx to autogenerate documentation from the docstrings, and it's easier to read for people familiar with those styles as well.  I like the [numpydoc](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/HOWTO_DOCUMENT.rst.txt) style guide.

Instead of setting to numbers, you probably want an `Enum` (enum34 is a pretty good backport) for `L1_HITS`, etc.

Your comment for the `l1_maxsize is None` seems misleading - isn't this size *unlimited* caching?  Same for the last case.

Overall a lot of the code in the cache itself seems like it could be simplified a bit, and that it could (and should?) be broken up into more helper functions.  In particular, the usage of a linked-list makes me a bit nervous - in my experience they are almost never the right data structure for the job. Additionally, more comments explaining some of the design decisions might be helpful - as is they aren't super intuitive.

Comment: Thanks for your quick feedback.  I have implemented most of the changes you recommended and they are available on [GitHub](https://github.com/3Top/lru2cache). I do not see how `typed` being truthy and `kwds` being falsy would encounter a `NameError` since withing it is on encountered if `kwds` is truthy as far as I can tell.  The reason I am using a linked-list is that I understood this to be the best data structure when you need to frequently re-order a list as with and LRU cache.

Comment: And in answer to what `_make_key` is doing, it is generating a unique key for each function or method including of all of its (optionally typed) args and kwargs.  This key is then used as the key for the local cache, as well as for a shared cache, such as Memcached.

Comment: @mjbrams `sorted_items` is defined in the `if kwds` section, and then referenced in the `if typed` section. I understood that's what `_make_key` is doing - I just don't understand why.  It seems that you could use something like the current module name, along with the function name, to generate a unique key.

Comment: within the `if typed` there is a second `if kwds`, perhaps I could nest this a little more elegantly.  You just made me realize I don't currently take into account the module name in `_make_key`, but in addition it needs to vary on args, kwds and in some cases their type, and result in a key that is Memcached compatible. Thanks again!